# Where is definition for document.startViewTransition?

Tags: typescript, view-transitions-api

In TS `document.startViewTransition` throws a
`Property 'startViewTransition' does not exist on type 'Document'` error.

I've tryied to add `lib: ["DOM"]` but it doesn't change anything.

Why is there TS definition for this new API ?

Answer (score 6):

The ViewTransition api is still a ["Candidate recommandation"](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-view-transitions-1/), so it's not embedded in TSs' definition yet.

I've found that `@types/dom-view-transitions` fit my needs though !